# Python setup.py clone the subfolder and use it as source code

Tags: python, git, python-import, setuptools, install-requires

The Python project intensively uses common declaration from another repository.

```
from *another_repository*.common import *class1*, *class2*.
```

How to properly integrate such folder within own repository, without copying it itself into the current project?
In `setuptools.setup` there is a field like `install_requires`. I have tried the next option:

```
install_requires = [..., 'another_repository @ git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/another_repository@master&subdirectory=common', ...]
```

But it does not work, since `common` folder does not contain any `setup.py` module.

Comment: add common repo as submodule ?

Comment: @rasjani is it any other way? It is gonna be used as a third-party without contributing to it.

Comment: if the files from the submodule are included as part of the source distribution or wheel (for example, included via MANIFEST.in file), there's nothing wrong with the approach. Relying on some external service at install time *is not a good idea* and will cause issues for random people.

Comment: Any chance you can contribute a setup.py to the other repository? If not, I also recommend the submodule approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and by thinking about the problem, I have found the next possible solutions:

1. Migrate all common code from the `another_repository/common` (dataclasses, routines, etc) to the other repository `common_repository`, and use it as a dependency.
2. Use a repo as a submodule it the current project.
3. Contribute a setup.py to the `another_repository/common`, to make it installable.